# Z-Index alike property for StackPanel children?

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I have a `StackPanel` that has two Items: `ToggleButton` and `ListBox`. To make the listBox looks like it's a part of the toggle button -by hiding the sharp edges

[image]

I'm thinking to give it negative margin so it moves upward, but this presumes that it's positioned under the StackPanel which is not the case, and when I give it negative margin it covers the button.
So is there a way to control how items inside `StackPanel` are stacked over each other, something like Z-Index in CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824518/why-zindex-is-not-considered-in-arrange-override-of-a-stackpanel That might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Panel.ZIndex` attached property. Set it to a larger value for the `ToggleButton` if you don't want the `ListBox` to cover it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Content="Toggle" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
    <ListBox Margin="0 -10 0 0" Panel.ZIndex="0">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: How is it available even if there is no parent `Panel`, even the intellisense couldn't recognize it?!

Comment: @mshwf `StackPanel` is a `Panel`.